# What are views for collections and when would you want to use them?

Tags: scala, view, scala-collections

In Scala, for many (all?) types of collections you can create views.

What exactly is a view and for which purposes are views useful?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Views are non-strict versions of collections. This means that the elements are calculated at access and not eagerly as in normal collections.

As an example take the following code:

```
val xs = List.tabulate(5)(_ + 1)
val ys = xs.view map { x => println(x); x * x }
```

Just this will not print anything but every access to the list will perform the calculation and print the value, i.e. every call to `ys.head` will result in `1` being printed. If you want to get a strict version of the collection again you can call `force` on it. In this case you will see all numbers printed out.

One use for views is when you need to traverse a collection of values which are expensive to compute and you only need one value at a time. Also views let you build lazy sequences by calling `toStream` on them that will also cache the evaluated elements.

Answer (score 15):

One use case is when you need to collect first result of elements transformation:

```
    case class Transform(n: Int) { println("Transform "+n)}
    val list = List(1,2,3,4,5)
    list.view.map(v => Transform(v)).collectFirst{case Transform(3) => println("found")}
```

Prints:

```
Transform 1
Transform 2
Transform 3
found
```

While:

```
    list.map(v => Transform(v)).collectFirst{case Transform(3) => println("found")}
```

Prints:

```
Transform 1
Transform 2
Transform 3
Transform 4
Transform 5
found
```

Comment: This is a very illustrative use case where view shines.Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

See [Views](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_42.html) from [Scala 2.8 Collections API](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections.html).

> Scala collections are by default strict in all their transformers, except for `Stream`, which implements all its transformer methods lazily. However, there is a systematic way to turn every collection into a lazy one and *vice versa*, which is based on collection views. A *view* is a special kind of collection that represents some base collection, but implements all transformers lazily.
>
> ...
>
> There are two reasons why you might want to consider using views. The first is performance. You have seen that by switching a collection to a view the construction of intermediate results can be avoided. These savings can be quite important.
>
> ...
>
> The second use case applies to views over mutable sequences. Many transformer functions on such views provide a window into the original sequence that can then be used to update selectively some elements of that sequence.

Answer (score 0):

view is used for lazy computation,but not for saving memory.

When you create a view against a collection, the memory has already been allocated forthe collection.

When creating the view with `val view = Range(1,9).view.`,  the collection has already been allocated the memory, if it is too large,say,`Range(1,1000000000)`, OOM can't be avoid