# Lazy evaluation steps : filtering a list

Tags: list, scala, collections, filter, lazy-evaluation

I have some questions regarding lazy evaluation in Scala.
This is the sample code:

```
val people=List(("Mark", 32), ("Bob", 22), ("Jane", 8), 
         ("Jill", 21), ("nick", 50), ("Nancy", 42), 
         ("Mike", 19), ("Sara", 12), ("Paula", 42), 
         ("John", 21))

def isOlderThan17(person: (String,Int)) = {
  println(s"isOlderThan 17 called for $person")
  val(_,age) = person
  age > 17
}

def nameStartsWithJ(person: (String, Int)) = {
  println(s"isNameStartsWithJ called for $person")
  val (name,_) = person
  name.startsWith("J")
}

println(people.view.filter(p => isOlderThan17(p))
                   .filter(p => nameStartsWithJ(p))
                   .last)
```

Output :

```
isOlderThan 17 called for (Mark,32)
isNameStartsWithJ called for (Mark,32)
isOlderThan 17 called for (Bob,22)
isNameStartsWithJ called for (Bob,22)
isOlderThan 17 called for (Jane,8)
isOlderThan 17 called for (Jill,21)
isNameStartsWithJ called for (Jill,21)
isOlderThan 17 called for (Mark,32)      //Here is the problem.
isNameStartsWithJ called for (Mark,32)
isOlderThan 17 called for (Bob,22)
isNameStartsWithJ called for (Bob,22)
isOlderThan 17 called for (Jane,8)
isOlderThan 17 called for (Jill,21)
isNameStartsWithJ called for (Jill,21)
isOlderThan 17 called for (nick,50)
isNameStartsWithJ called for (nick,50)
isOlderThan 17 called for (Nancy,42)
isNameStartsWithJ called for (Nancy,42)
isOlderThan 17 called for (Mike,19)
isNameStartsWithJ called for (Mike,19)
isOlderThan 17 called for (Sara,12)
isOlderThan 17 called for (Paula,42)
isNameStartsWithJ called for (Paula,42)
isOlderThan 17 called for (John,21)
isNameStartsWithJ called for (John,21)
(John,21)
```

Why did the evaluation have to be restarted (back again from "Mark") after "Jill" had been found? Why didn't it continue the evaluation until the end of the list?

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be related to the implementation of `last` in `view`. If you do it this way it won't restart:

```
people.view
      .filter(isOlderThan17(_))
      .filter(nameStartsWithJ(_))
      .fold(None)((x, y) => Some(y))
```

Looks like `last` is trying to access `head` twice, which in your case means you need to find the first element of `people.view.filter(isOlderThan17(_))` twice and so `view` has to recompute it two times.

**UPDATE**

Here's the definition of `last` in `TraversableLike`:

```
def last: A = {
    var lst = head
    for (x <- this)
      lst = x
    lst
  }
```

The first element is indeed accessed twice.

Answer (score 1):

> Why did the evaluation have to be restarted (back again from "Mark")
>   after "Jill" had been found?

Because each `filter` results in a new collection that contains only the filtered items. Use a stream to avoid this:

```
println(people.toStream
              .filter(p => isOlderThan17(p))
              .filter(p => nameStartsWithJ(p))
              .last)
```

From [Stream vs Views vs Iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159000/stream-vs-views-vs-iterators)

> Stream is a lazy list indeed. In fact, in Scala, a Stream is a List
>   whose tail is a lazy val. Once computed, a value stays computed and is
>   reused. Or, as you say, the values are cached.

In this case you're only composing filters so you might as well just combine the two predicates and do the filtering only once:

```
println(people.filter(p => isOlderThan17(p) && nameStartsWithJ(p))
              .last)
```

Comment: If OP only wants to find the last element `Stream` is not very memory efficient.

Comment: Won't the view in this case compose the filter methods into one filter method? I don't think each filter should result in a new collection in this example.

Comment: Filter always results in a new collection, just look at the signature of `filter(p: (A) ⇒ Boolean): List[A]`.