# MapView(<not computed>) in Scala

Tags: scala, dictionary

I started learning Scala but I found a confusing problem about `map`. My code is like this:

```
val mymap = Map(1 -> "james",2 -> "justin")
println(mymap.view.mapValues(x => "hi" + x))
println(mymap.view.mapValues(x => x.toUpperCase))
```

but the result is

```
MapView(<not computed>)
MapView(<not computed>)
```

I am using `view.mapValues` because `.map` is deprecated. Any suggestion or doc I need to read about this?

Comment: Add `toMap` at the end. Also, read the [**docs**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/View.html) and check the [**faq**](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/index.html#what-is-the-difference-between-view-stream-and-iterator).

Comment: I already try adding toMap but got and error of  `value toMap is not a member of Unit` thats why I ask to SO

Comment: You are adding `toMap` to the `println` probably... which obviously won't work.

Comment: I even try use this `val test: MapView[Int, String] = mymap.view.mapValues(x => "hi" + x)` and   `println(test)` but still the result is not computed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following:

```scala
val mymap = Map(1 -> "james",2 -> "justin")
println(mymap.view.mapValues(x => "hi" + x).toMap)
println(mymap.view.mapValues(x => x.toUpperCase).toMap)
```

Note that in Scala 2.12 calling [mapValues](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/MapLike.scala#L105) returned a `Map`. In Scala 2.13 [`mapValues` was deprecated](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/collection/Map.scala#L228), with the message:

```scala
@deprecated("Use .view.mapValues(f). A future version will include a strict version of this method (for now, .view.mapValues(f).toMap).", "2.13.0")
```

In order to get a `Map` you should call `.view.mapValues(f).toMap`. If you don't call `toMap`, you get an instance of [MapView](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/collection/MapView.scala#L51), which is not materilized. For more information please read the great post: [Stream vs Views vs Iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5159000/2359227).