# scala.collection.MapView$MapValues cannot be cast to scala.collection.immutable.Map

Tags: scala

I have some code that used to work under Scala 2.12 but now fails under 2.13.

Essentially my calls look like so:

`Controller -> Service -> Actor -> Repo`

My **controller** looks like this:

```scala
complete {
  dep.chunkService.getChunksWithSubtitlesByDistribution(id, chunkState).map(
    _.right.map(
    chunkMap => StatusResult(
                  Meta(OK),
                  chunkMap.extractChunkDtoList,
                  chunkMap.extractSubtitleDtoList)): ToResponseMarshallable)
}
```

And the error I get is:

> scala.collection.MapView$MapValues cannot be cast to scala.collection.immutable.Map

It happens on this line of the controller:

```scala
  chunkMap => StatusResult(
```

The **service** method that is called by the controller has the signature:

```scala
def getChunksWithSubtitlesByDistribution(distributionId: UUID, state: Option[ChunkState]): 
        Future[Either[DistributionNotFoundError, Map[Chunk, List[Subtitle]]]]
```

The service sets up an Actor that makes the call to the Repo like so:

```scala
sender ! chunkRepo.getChunksWithSubtitlesByDistribution(distributionId, state).right.map(_.mapValues(_.sortWith((a, b) => a.start < b.start) ) )
```

It is that value which will be returned by `chunkService.getChunksWithSubtitlesByDistribution`

`chunkRepo.getChunksWithSubtitlesByDistribution` returns this:

```scala
result match {
   case Nil => Left(DistributionNotFoundError(distributionId))
   case rs =>
     Right(
       rs.flatten
         .groupBy { case (c, s) => c }
           .mapValues(pairs => pairs.map { case (c, ss) => ss }.flatten)
           .toMap
     )
}
```

Not sure where in the chain the "MapView" comes into play, or how to get it to convert to a "normal" map?

Comment: `_.mapValues` in `2.13` returns a **View** and is deprecated. Replace it with `.view.mapValues(f).toMap`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez That did the trick! Please allow me the privilege of awarding you internet points. If you could, make your comment into an answer and I'll select it.

Comment: That on its own is not really worth it as an answer and I am pretty sure the question will be closed either as _"caused by a typo"_ or a duplicate that I am too lazy to search for :p - Anyways, I am glad it helped :)

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez it surprises me that they would change the return type and mark it as deprecated. Essentially this is breaking functionality between 2.12 and 2.13, so really they could have just removed the function all together as it doesn't even return the same type as it once did.

Comment: Well `2.13` break a lot of things just like any other major **Scala** release.

Comment: Does this help you? [MapView(<not computed>) in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65289749/2359227)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a commenter has pointed out, the return type of `mapValues(f)` has changed between Scala `2.12` and `2.13`.  The code to correct is:

```scala
sender ! chunkRepo.getChunksWithSubtitlesByDistribution(distributionId, state)
  .right.map(_**.view**.mapValues(_.sortWith((a, b) => a.start < b.start) )**.toMap** )
```

**changed code**