# Stream v. SeqView

Tags: scala

What are use cases to use `SeqView` over a `Stream`?

```
scala> List(1,2).view
res34: scala.collection.SeqView[Int,List[Int]] = SeqView(...)

scala> List(1,2).view.toStream
res33: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(1, ?)
```

Perhaps if you need to access the middle of a `Stream` and it's costly to access `Stream` elements, then you'd use the `SeqView`?

Comment: This is nearly a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159000/stream-vs-views-vs-iterators

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798043/what-is-the-difference-between-the-methods-iterator-and-view and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361478/what-are-views-for-collections-and-when-would-you-want-to-use-them

Comment: thanks - I'll delete this question

Comment: View is broken, don't use it. [Point.](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scala-language/uRt7Nvj3o6k/ufiCOr47aDAJ)

Comment: @Kevin Meredith Nah, this question and the answer do give a nice, concise response to what you proposed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SeqView` is not cheaper than `Stream`. In fact, it's more costly to access an element in `SeqView` than `Stream`, because `Stream` caches the results it computed but `SeqView`(or any other `View`s) not.